# Still not getting proper resolution landscape, portrait images back from the API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

i follow the steps 
Login to into your client application settings on https://instagram.com/developer/
Click Manage Clients on top nav menu.
Locate your API Client, and click Edit.
Click the Migrations Tab for your API Client application, and check the box that says "Non square media".
Click Update Client.

and enabled the Non Square media and uploaded couple of landscape and portriot photos, still i am getting square photos only;please find the example response for still showing 640 * 640 ;please help;

{ caption: "", commentCount: 0, comments: null, createdTime: "Oct 15, 2015", deleted: null, height: 640, id: null, providerImageId: null, thumbnailInfo: { caption: null, commentCount: 0, comments: null, createdTime: null, deleted: null, height: 150, id: null, providerImageId: null, thumbnailInfo: null, type: null, url: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/12144260_893144404097052_1454548341_n.jpg", username: null, width: 150 }, type: null, url: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12144260_893144404097052_1454548341_n.jpg", username: "anilk", width: 640 },

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload images from the iOS Hook? From what I can tell with my own tests, landscape and portrait images in Instagram only work when selecting an image from the gallery within the Instagram app. When passing an image via the hook it just crops it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nonsquare/media/recent/?client_id=[CLIENT-ID] or https://instagram.com/explore/tags/nonsquare/. There are many non-square images.

When you upload picture in Instagram, application use square as default. To upload non-square image, just click small gray button in left-down corner of image before filter's selection.